# Почему удаляется содержимое ячеек HTML таблицы при их перемешивании?

Tags: javascript, html, таблицы

В приведенном ниже примере функция shuffleNumbers() должна перемешать числа в таблице случайным образом. Однако, вместо того, чтобы поменять местами пустую ячейку и соседнюю с ней ячейку с числом, функция оставляет пустыми обе ячейки. Проблема решилась добавлением строк, взятых сейчас в комментарий. Я не могу понять  причину возникновения проблемы так же, как и ее решение :). Как может повлиять задание несуществующих координат для заменяемой ячейки  markedCell = {r:-1, c:-1}; в конце итерации цикла, если в начале следующей итерации происходит задание новых координат?

```js
let markedCell = {r:-1, c:-1}; // ячейка с числом должна меняться местами 
let emptyCell = {r:3, c:3};   // с пустой ячейкой
let shuffle = document.querySelector('button[id = shuffle]');
shuffle.addEventListener('click', shuffleNumbers);
function shuffleNumbers(){
    while (!(emptyCell.r == 0 && emptyCell.c == 0)){ // перемешивание чисел
        let rand = Math.round(Math.random());
        let rand1 =  Math.round(Math.random()); 
        if(rand == 0){
            markedCell.c = emptyCell.c;
            if (rand1 == 0){
                markedCell.r = emptyCell.r > 0 ? emptyCell.r - 1 : emptyCell.r + 1;
            } else {
                markedCell.r = emptyCell.r < 3 ? emptyCell.r + 1 : emptyCell.r - 1;
            }            
        } else {
            markedCell.r = emptyCell.r;
            if (rand1 == 0){
                markedCell.c = emptyCell.c > 0 ? emptyCell.c - 1 : emptyCell.c + 1;
            } else {
                markedCell.c = emptyCell.c < 3 ? emptyCell.c + 1 : emptyCell.c - 1;
            } 
        }
        mTab.rows[emptyCell.r].cells[emptyCell.c].innerHTML = mTab.rows[markedCell.r].cells[markedCell.c].innerHTML;
        mTab.rows[markedCell.r].cells[markedCell.c].innerHTML = ' ';
        emptyCell = markedCell;
//        markedCell = {r:-1, c:-1};
    }
    while(emptyCell.r < 3){ // возврат пустой ячейки в правый нижний угол
        markedCell.r = emptyCell.r + 1;
        markedCell.c = emptyCell.c;
        mTab.rows[emptyCell.r].cells[emptyCell.c].innerHTML = mTab.rows[markedCell.r].cells[markedCell.c].innerHTML;
        mTab.rows[markedCell.r].cells[markedCell.c].innerHTML = ' ';
        emptyCell = markedCell;
//        markedCell = {r:-1, c:-1};
    }   
    while(emptyCell.c < 3){
        markedCell.c = emptyCell.c + 1;
        markedCell.r = emptyCell.r;
        mTab.rows[emptyCell.r].cells[emptyCell.c].innerHTML = mTab.rows[markedCell.r].cells[markedCell.c].innerHTML;
        mTab.rows[markedCell.r].cells[markedCell.c].innerHTML = ' ';
        emptyCell = markedCell;
//    markedCell = {r:-1, c:-1};
    }   
}
```

```css
*{
  padding:0px; margin:0px; box-sizing:border-box;
}
#mTab{
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */
    font-size: 250%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
}
#mTab td{
    border:solid 1px #666666;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#mTab td textarea{
    display:block;
    outline:0px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#resTab{
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */
    font-size: 150%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
}
#resTab td{
    border:solid 0px #666666;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#resTab td textarea{
    display:block;
    outline:0px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Пятнашки</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mTab">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id = 'shuffle'>Перемешать </button>
  <button id = 'check'>Проверить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю не мешать ячейки, а просто назначать им соответствующий контент.

Функция `randomize(min,max)` выдает массив чисел от `min` включительно, до `max` включительно. При этом все значения случайным образом разбросаны.

Функция `shuffle(table)` принимает таблицу, перебирает первым делом вызывает `randomize()` для нашего диапазона (в дальнейшем его можно получать через кол-во ячеек в таблице - 1 => `randomize(1,table.querySelectorAll('td').length-1)`). Так мы получаем универсальную функцию, заполняющую ячейки случайными номерами.

Затем перебирает строки и ячейки в них, назначая `textContent` каждой ячейке соответствующее значение из массива. Последней ячейке ничего не достается. Но это работает, хотя можно организовать проверку.

```js
document.getElementById('shuffle').addEventListener('click', () => {shuffle(document.querySelector('table'))});

function randomize(from,to){
    const random_order = new Set();
    while(random_order.size < (to - from + 1)){
        random_order.add(Math.floor(Math.random() * (to - from + 1)) + from);
    }
    return [...random_order];
}

function shuffle(table){
    const rand_nums = randomize(1,15);
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
    rows.forEach((r,i) => {
        const cells = r.querySelectorAll('td');
        cells.forEach((c,j) => {
            c.textContent = rand_nums[i*cells.length + j];
        })
    })
}
```

```css
*{
  padding:0px; margin:0px; box-sizing:border-box;
}
#mTab{
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */
    font-size: 250%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
}
#mTab td{
    border:solid 1px #666666;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#mTab td textarea{
    display:block;
    outline:0px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#resTab{
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */
    font-size: 150%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
}
#resTab td{
    border:solid 0px #666666;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#resTab td textarea{
    display:block;
    outline:0px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Пятнашки</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
  <table id="mTab">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id = 'shuffle'>Перемешать </button>
  <button id = 'check'>Проверить</button>
</body>
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
Пришлось немного усложнить)) Но смысл остался прежним в том, что обрабатывается массив с данными, а уже затем результат переносится в таблицу.

`getNeibors()` возвращает массив индексов возможных соседей пустой клетки без предыдущего сдвинутого соседа (чтобы не зацикливать перемещения). Проверяются границы таблицы в основном.

`shuffle(table, move_num)` принимает таблицу и количество перемещений со случайным соседом. Формирует базовый массив элементов с номерами в изначальном положении исходя из размеров таблицы.
Задает пустую ячейку со значением `''`(`empty`) объявляет `prev`для дальнейшего контроля перемещения.

И в цикле `while` move_num раз вызывается функция `moveToEmpty()`, которая получает соседей пустой ячейки, выбирает случайного из них и меняет местами с `empty`.

После цикла, опять же смещением соседних ячеек пустая ячейка спускается в низ, а затем и вправо.

И только после этого значения ячейкам таблицы назначаются согласно данным в массиве `arr`.

```js
document.getElementById('shuffle').addEventListener('click', () => {shuffle(document.querySelector('table'), 100)});

function getNeibors(arr, index, row_len, prev){
    let neibors = []; // indices!!!
    if(index%row_len != 0) neibors.push(index-1);                 // not the far left cell in row
    if(index%row_len != row_len-1) neibors.push(index+1);         // not the far right cell in row
    if(index >= row_len) neibors.push(index-row_len);             // not in top row
    if(index < arr.length - row_len) neibors.push(index+row_len); // not in bottom
    if(prev) neibors = neibors.filter(i => i != prev);
    return neibors;
}

function shuffle(table, move_num){
    const row_num = table.querySelectorAll('tr').length;
    const row_len = table.querySelector('tr').querySelectorAll('td').length;
    const arr_len = row_len*row_num;
    const arr = [];
    for(let i=1; i < arr_len; i++){ // Initial Array of the table
        arr.push(i);
    }
    let prev = null;
    let empty = arr_len-1;
    arr[empty] = '';
    
    while(move_num > 0){         // Move move_num times
        moveToEmpty();
        move_num--;
    }
    
    const empty_col = empty%row_len;
    for(let i = empty + row_len; i < arr.length; i+=row_len){ // Move empty cell to the bottom
        [arr[i], arr[empty]] = [arr[empty], arr[i]];
        empty = i;
    }
    for(let i = empty + 1; i < arr.length; i++){              // Move empty cell to the right
        [arr[i], arr[empty]] = [arr[empty], arr[i]];
        empty = i;
    }
    
    const rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');               // This part hasn`t changed at all
    rows.forEach((r,i) => {
        const cells = r.querySelectorAll('td');
        cells.forEach((c,j) => {
            c.textContent = arr[i*cells.length + j];
        })
    })
    
    function moveToEmpty(){
        const neibors = getNeibors(arr,empty,row_len,prev);
        let random_index = (neibors.length > 1)? neibors[(Math.floor(Math.random()*(neibors.length)))] : neibors[0];
        [arr[empty],arr[random_index]] = [arr[random_index],arr[empty]];
        prev = empty;
        empty = random_index;
    }
}
```

```css
*{
  padding:0px; margin:0px; box-sizing:border-box;
}
#mTab{
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */
    font-size: 250%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
}
#mTab td{
    border:solid 1px #666666;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#mTab td textarea{
    display:block;
    outline:0px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
#resTab{
    border:solid 5px #666666;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; /* Гарнитура текста */
    font-size: 150%; /* Размер шрифта в процентах */ 
}
#resTab td{
    border:solid 0px #666666;
    width:60px;
    height:60px;
    max-height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#resTab td textarea{
    display:block;
    outline:0px;
    border:0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
  <table id="mTab">
    <tr>
        <td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td><td>8</td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>9</td><td>10</td><td>11</td><td>12</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>13</td><td>14</td><td>15</td><td> </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br>
  <button id = 'shuffle'>Перемешать </button>
  <button id = 'check'>Проверить</button>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, решение лаконичное и красивое. К сожалению, в данном случае просто заполнять ячейки случайными номерами не годится. Я делаю головоломку 15. Если расставить числа случайно, высока вероятность, что головоломку будет невозможно решить.

Comment: Это интересно. Сейчас доработаю)) Не думаю, что будет намного сложнее.

Comment: Не совсем уверен в случайном отборе из соседей, там надо проверить все ли варианты возвращаются. Также надо все разделить на более мелкие функции, значения передавать и вообще доработать есть чего.